# std::for_each equivalent that does not dereference the iterators

Tags: c++, foreach, iterator

Is there a function like std::for_each that directly passes the iterators instead of the result of dereferencing them?

What we have

```
std::vector<int> ints;
std::for_each(ints.begin(), ints.end(),
[](int i)
{
  //how to get the iterator of this element???
}
```

what I am searching for

```
for_each_iterator(ints.begin(), ints.end(),
[](const std::vector<int>::const_iterator &i)
{
  //we know the iterator here
}
```

Of course it is fairly trivial to write such a function, but I am asking if there exists a standard solution from `std::`, `std::tr1::` or `boost::`

Comment: What would you use it for?

Comment: I ran across this several times. Currently I am trying to zip together two iterators to compare the ranges they represent (instead of the values they point to). This is for unit testing purposes.

Comment: *Unless* iterators are elements themselves, the idea of "iterating over iterators" sound a bit paradoxical to me.

Comment: You want to verify that the ranges are the same? A plain straight comparison of the begin/end iterators in the two sequence will tell you whether they are the same or not. I.e. given the same begin and end, all of the iterators (and the elements they refer to) in the middle will be the same. That is, if you want to test *equality* you want to test the *values* and the iterators will not help, if you want to test *identity* you just need to test the original iterators, no need to verify every element in the sequence.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: You are right. I forgot that both are pointing to the same structure and therefore thought I would have to check each element of the range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing in the Standard library. But it is not that hard to implement it yourself:

```
template<typename It, typename Functor >
void iterate(It begin, It end, Functor && f)
{
    while ( begin != end ) { f(begin); ++begin; }
}
```

And use it as:

```
iterate(ints.begin(), ints.end(), [](std::vector<int>::iterator it)
              {
                 //use it
              });
```

Or use manual loop.

Comment: Uhm... the functor should be probably taken by *universal-reference*. Other than that, I cannot see any good use case for the function :)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: I edited it. But I don't know why it is better to accept by universal-reference? Does it make any difference?

Comment: Not just avoiding the copy (it won't), but you are allowed to pass a stateful object and it will update the object in place. Note that this is different from the behavior of `std::for_each` in the standard, but is also more flexible.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: not necessarily more flexible, because you cannot pass the functor by value. With `for_each()`, you can use `ref(f)` to pass the functor by reference

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: I've seen argument against stateful functor. Do you think it is good thing?

Comment: @Nawaz: *In general*, no. Some algorithms forbid stateful functors (in particular, predicates). But some algorithms allow that. `for_each()`, for instance, does allow that.

Comment: @AndyProwl: I realized that. That is why I've already rephrased my comment :P

Comment: @Nawaz: I guess it depends... the problem of stateful functors (with standard algorithms) is that the guarantees are usually not enough to manage the state correctly, for example, the standard takes the functors by value, and allows for copying internally. For example, a common implementation of `remove_if` first calls `find_if` (creating a copy of the functor) and then continues from there on, which means that until the first hit, one predicate will be used, after that first hit a different one.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: concerning the avoiding of the copy, why do you say it won't? A universal reference will turn into an l-value reference, so there will be no copy. And it will bind to rvalues as well.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Exactly my thought.

Comment: ... but in other cases the guarantees are stricter and you can take advantage of state. For example, `for_each` in the standard takes the range and the functor, and returns a copy of the functor after it has been applied to all elements in order. I guess you don't need *universal-references* if you do that in your code (i.e. return the functor by value after applying it to all elements/iterators in this case)

Comment: @AndyProwl: You are right in the lvalue case... I was thinking on the rvalue case, where the compiler can elide the copy or move if the copy cannot be elided and the functor supports it.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: There will be no copy even in the rvalue case. The reference will simply be bound to the temporary

Comment: @AndyProwl: my point was that there would not be a copy in the rvalue case either way. If it is passing by value, the copy can be either elided or transformed into a move.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: I see. Yes, indeed there would be no copy. However, if the template accepts an `F` rather than an `F&&`, you can still pass your functor by reference by using `ref()` or `cref()`, as you would do in the case of `for_each()`. So you have the choice basically.

Comment: I think it would be more flexible (though more complicated) to implement an iterator wrapper so that you could use all the standard algorithms with them instead of just implementing one algorithm. But I guess that would be for general purpose use, not if you know you're only using it once in a specific way.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking at the wrong level of abstraction. The `for_each` algorithm applies the function to *each of the **elements*** in the range. If you need to operate on the iterators, you should unroll your loop:

```
for (auto it = ints.begin(); it != ints.end(); ++it ) {
   // do something
}
```

What you are asking for would be trivially implementable, just not that useful in my opinion. Either you control how iterators are updated in the loop (as in the code above) or there is little use for the iterator itself. What do you want to get out of the iterator?

Comment: You just rephrased his question

Comment: @qdii: The last part maybe, but the first sentence is right on and not in the question: he is looking at the wrong level of abstraction.

Answer (score 1):

I can only think of how using a wrapper for iterators, I can't think of a way using only standard algorithms, so you still have to write some auxiliary code. Example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct it_wrapper {
   it_wrapper(const T& t) : it(t) { }

   T operator*() const {
      return it;
   }

   it_wrapper& operator++() {
      ++it;
      return *this;
   }

   it_wrapper operator++(int) {
      it_wrapper old = *this;
      ++it;
      return old;
   }

   bool operator!=(const it_wrapper& rhs) {
      return it != rhs.it;
   }

   T it;
};

template<typename T>
it_wrapper<T> wrap(const T& t) {
   return it_wrapper<T>(t);
}

int main() {
   std::vector<int> v { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

   std::for_each(wrap(v.begin()), wrap(v.end()), [](decltype(v.begin()) i) {
      std::cout << *i << '\n';
   });
}
```

Prints

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3
>
> 4

I'm not sure how this is more helpful than just using a `for`-loop, but you must have your reasons...

Comment: I also thought about that. Could there be a standard solution (as described in my question) for this indirector?

Comment: @Nobody not that I know of, unless you want to fill a vector with iterators and iterate over that vector, which would be wasteful. Is this an intellectual exercise or are you just really averse to writing classes and `for`-loops?

Comment: If I had to pick then I would say the latter. The last year I have spend realizing that 2/3 of my code already exists as a standard solution so I try to avoid this now.

Comment: @Nobody yeah, that's a good mentality to have. But I'm pretty sure that all the standard algorithms will give you elements of the range to work with, not iterators, since that functionality is already provided by the humble `for` in one line: `for (auto i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i) dowork(i);`